# I want to draw the 3D line from the output of accelerometer of android mobile using opengl es

Tags: android, for-loop, opengl-es

I want to draw 3D line using OpenGL Es 1.0 and I am thinking to make an application which draw 3D lines after getting the coordinate value from the sensors(Magnetometer and Accelerometer) in Android Mobile Phone.

I wanted to use 'for' statement to draw many lines but I realized that there is a problem that using 'for' statement in the following 'onDrawFrame' method.

```
       public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
         gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

         gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
         gl.glLoadIdentity();
         gl.glRotatef(xAngle, 1, 0, 0);
         gl.glRotatef(yAngle, 0, 1, 0);

         for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
         {
             line1.drawDataLine(gl);    
         }
       }
```

Above code is what I tried to do. Let's say I want to draw 10 lines and 'line1.drawDataLine(gl)' method is to draw the lines from the values of sensors.

The problem is that whenever I use the 'for' statement, debugging is okay but it didn't work properly.

Is it impossible to use 'for' statement in the 'onDrawFrame' method?

Comment: Please explain how to draw the lines using x,y,z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't this method draw 10 overlapping lines? I think you should probably create a separate object that defines the logic, then create an instance in your Renderer class and plug that into onDraw().

Comment: Really thanks for your answer. You are right. That was my mistake which i don't explain about 'drawDataLine' method. This method draw lines after getting X,Y,Z coordinates from the sensors(magnetometer, accelerometer). So, It is supposed to draw line in different place.

and weird thing is that when I use 'for' statement like above, even one line is not drawn at all. so I thought that 'for' statement didn't work.